# GridView take a Row

Tags: c#, asp.net

net 4 and c#.

I have a GridView, I would like take a Row when in Edit Mode in my code and find a control.

Here my code, but does not work, it takes only the first row for the GridView.

Any ideas?

```
protected void uxManageSlotsDisplayer_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    switch (e.Row.RowType)
    {
        case DataControlRowType.DataRow:

        // Take Row in Edit Mode DOES NOT WORK PROEPRLY
        if (e.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
        {
            Label myTest = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("uxTest");
        }
        break;

    }
```

MY CODE EXAMPLES:
[GridView row in edit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170261/gridview-row-in-edit-mode)

SOLUTIONS:
After reading this: [Gridview row editing - dynamic binding to a DropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833490/asp-net-3-5-gridview-row-editing-dynamic-binding-to-a-dropdownlist)

```
        protected void uxList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow &&
                (e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == DataControlRowState.Edit)
        {
            // Here you will get the Control you need like:
            Label dl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("uxLblTest");
            dl.Text = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        }
    }
```

Comment: We need more information: what row do you need, the one that's the current selected row, or the row that's being edited, or multiple rows in edit mode ?

Comment: Hi i need the Row being edited (the row is in edit mode), so should be a unique ROW in edit mode (after the user click edit). any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
Added check for `DataRow`

```
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
```

instead of

```
 if (e.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
```

Comment: thanks but did not solve the problem... any other ideas? no one in SO seems know the answer :-(

Comment: Edited! I have added the check for RowType. I have similar code in a few for my apps and they work.

Comment: Hi, now is working but ONLY for the FIRST Row in the GridView... very strange? What do you think? I need the same for every row in the GridView. Please let me now many thanks

Comment: Yes in fact, if i put in edit mode the first role your code is working. If i select the second or others rows does not work. quite strange

Comment: Have you tried the RowEditing event? you'll have to have `var currentRow = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];` to get the current row.

Comment: im trying but im now able to make it.

Comment: Here the code im using, i need to get the label in edit mode and change the text. May I ask you to write a simple line of code for my understanding??? I really appreciate it im a really beginner http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170261/gridview-row-in-edit-mode

Comment: hi here the solution if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow &&
                (e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == DataControlRowState.Edit)
 hope can help!

Answer (score 1):

you shoud set EditItemIndex in the grid before datatabind. you can do it in RowEditing event,
as in this example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowediting.aspx

Regards,
Stefano

Comment: Hi Stefano, I try your suggestion, but I am really a beginner and I am not able to work it out. I posted my code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170261/gridview-row-in-edit-mode could you kind me show an implementation? thanks once again