# GridView row in edit mode

Tags: c#, asp.net

I posted similar question before, but I still have some problem with it. I use asp.net 4 and c#.

Please help me to understand I need to change the TEXT for the Label uxTest when a user click the EDIT button for a single row.

Any idea? thanks guys once again and sorry if looks like a duplicates question.

---

```
       <%@ Page Language="C#" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <script runat="server">

      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
          // Create a new table.
          DataTable taskTable = new DataTable("TaskList");

          // Create the columns.
          taskTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
          taskTable.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
          taskTable.Columns.Add("IsComplete", typeof(bool) );

          //Add data to the new table.
          for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
          {
            DataRow tableRow = taskTable.NewRow();
            tableRow["Id"] = i;
            tableRow["Description"] = "Task " + i.ToString();
            tableRow["IsComplete"] = false;            
            taskTable.Rows.Add(tableRow);
          }

          //Persist the table in the Session object.
          Session["TaskTable"] = taskTable;

          //Bind data to the GridView control.
          BindData();
        }

      }

      protected void TaskGridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
      {
        TaskGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        //Bind data to the GridView control.
        BindData();
      }

      protected void TaskGridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
      {
        //Set the edit index.
        TaskGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        //Bind data to the GridView control.
        BindData();
      }

      protected void TaskGridView_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
      {
        //Reset the edit index.
        TaskGridView.EditIndex = -1;
        //Bind data to the GridView control.
        BindData();
      }

      protected void TaskGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
      {    
        //Retrieve the table from the session object.
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["TaskTable"];

        //Update the values.
        GridViewRow row = TaskGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Id"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;
        dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Description"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text;
        dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["IsComplete"] = ((CheckBox)(row.Cells[3].Controls[0])).Checked;

        //Reset the edit index.
        TaskGridView.EditIndex = -1;

        //Bind data to the GridView control.
        BindData();
      }

      private void BindData()
      {
        TaskGridView.DataSource = Session["TaskTable"];
        TaskGridView.DataBind();
      }
    </script>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <title>GridView example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

          <asp:GridView ID="TaskGridView" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
            AllowPaging="True"
            OnRowEditing="TaskGridView_RowEditing"         
            OnRowCancelingEdit="TaskGridView_RowCancelingEdit" 
            OnRowUpdating="TaskGridView_RowUpdating"
            OnPageIndexChanging="TaskGridView_PageIndexChanging" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False">
              <Columns>
                  <asp:TemplateField>
                  <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Label ID="uxTest" runat="server" Text="TEST"></asp:Label>
                  </EditItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
              </Columns>
          </asp:GridView>

        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

---

Code solutions:

```
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow &&
                    (e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == DataControlRowState.Edit){
Label dl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("uxLblTest");// Retrive control here
}
```

Comment: Why not editing your previous question then... OR at least give us the link ?

Comment: Sorry i did not think about it, now i did it. Please try this code. I almost spent two days on it but no way im able to get this label. any ideas? many thanks

Comment: I get the frustration, but could you try to reduce the amount of code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to change it, your ItemTemplate and EditItemTemplate can have completely different data/controls.  Below I'm show 2 different labels (see the ID's) for the Item/Edit templates.  You can change anyway you want, but this is the basic approach to have different view/edit modes.

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test Column">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="uxTest" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.TestColumn") %>'>
                    </asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="uxTestEditMode" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.TestColumn") %>'>
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```