# how to bind drop down list at edit item template Edit mode occurs in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0

i just want to bind two drop down list dynamically when grid view in row editing mode. here i declares one code block that dynamically fetches that row state and binds up those two drop down list.

here is code :

```
  protected void GV_ViewCustomers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
          ...............
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && (e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == DataControlRowState.Edit)
            {
                using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
                {
                    DropDownList dl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DDL_Types1");
                    dl.DataSource = db.PartyTypes.Select(t => t).ToList();
                    dl.DataBind();
                    dl.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "type_id").ToString();
                    DropDownList dl1 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DDL_CountryNames1");
                    dl1.DataSource = db.Countries.Select(c => c).ToList();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "country_id").ToString()))
                    {
                        dl1.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "country_id").ToString();
                        DropDownList dl2 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DDL_StateNames1");
                        dl2.DataSource = db.States.Where(s => s.country_id.Equals(int.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "country_id").ToString()))).Select(s => s).ToList();
                        dl2.DataBind();
                    }
                    DataRowView rowView1 = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
                    if (rowView1["UserOFC"] != null)
                    {
                        (e.Row.FindControl("chk_UserOFC1") as CheckBox).Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(e.Row.DataItem.Equals("UserOFC").ToString());
                    }
                    if (rowView1["UserVAT"] != null)
                    {
                        (e.Row.FindControl("chk_UserVAT1") as CheckBox).Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(e.Row.DataItem.Equals("UserVAT").ToString());
                    }
                    if (rowView1["UserINV"] != null)
                    {
                        (e.Row.FindControl("chk_UserINV1") as CheckBox).Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(e.Row.DataItem.Equals("UserINV").ToString());
                    }
                    if (rowView1["UserNone"] != null)
                    {
                        (e.Row.FindControl("chk_UserNone1") as CheckBox).Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(e.Row.DataItem.Equals("UserNone").ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
..................
}
```

Is this right method to binds drop down list at row editing mode.

please help me....

Comment: Do you get any error or issue with this?

Comment: no this not binds up this drop down list. how ever i have doubt this is not correct way to binds up drop down list and checkbox at row editing mode.

Comment: I think you are in the row editing event so this is also fine.
You can do this binding in RowDataBinding event by identifying the edit rows of the grid.

Comment: see question again i think i miss upper event line.

Comment: yeah.. That event is also correct.There is another event called RowDataBining. You can do the binding in that event also.
Your effort is fine. :)

Comment: have u any sample code.

Comment: see this [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833490/gridview-row-editing-dynamic-binding-to-a-dropdownlist)

Comment: Your method is correct.Since the code is same and the event is the only different.

Comment: are u telling me to use gridview_databinding event for that.

Comment: No need to use that.Your method is just fine. 
While we coding there can be many ways to do same thing. 
That can be decide according to the requirement and other facts.

Comment: ok. but i can not detect while i debugging with whole RowDataBount event. when user fires row editing button.

Comment: Row databound fires after the data has been bind to the grid.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine.But there are some other ways.

Comment: As I mentioned in the above comment. You can bind the data in RowDataBinding Event.
And also if you use jquery or java script to bind data,you can use javascript or jquery methods to bind the data.