# Binding data to dropdownlist control which is an edittemplate for my gridview asp.net but the datasource is in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

So i have a gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvExamSched" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" PageSize="30" Width="1030px" AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" OnRowDataBound="gvExamSched_RowDataBound">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" ItemStyle-Width="10%" ReadOnly="true"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="FIRST_NAME" HeaderText="FIRST_NAME" SortExpression="FIRST_NAME" ReadOnly="true" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="MIDDLE_NAME" HeaderText="MIDDLE_NAME" SortExpression="MIDDLE_NAME" ReadOnly="true"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="LAST_NAME" HeaderText="LAST_NAME" SortExpression="LAST_NAME" ReadOnly="true"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="EXTN" HeaderText="EXTN" SortExpression="EXTN" ReadOnly="true"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="OR #" HeaderText="OR #" SortExpression="OR #" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="DATE" HeaderText="DATE" SortExpression="DATE" ItemStyle-Width="15%" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TIME_FROM" SortExpression="TIME_FROM">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTimeFrom" runat="server" Width="80px"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TIME_FROM") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TIME_TO" HeaderText="TIME_TO" SortExpression="TIME_TO" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ROOM" HeaderText="ROOM" SortExpression="ROOM" />
                        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                    </Columns>
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

Now the dropdownlist (ddlTimeFrom) its data comes from the code behin (c#)
which is this:

```
private void BindTime()
    {
        DateTime StartTime = DateTime.ParseExact("00:00", "HH:mm", null);
        DateTime EndTime = DateTime.ParseExact("23:55", "HH:mm", null);
        TimeSpan Interval = new TimeSpan(0,5,0);
        ddlTimeFrom.Items.Clear();
        ddlTimeTo.Items.Clear();

        while (StartTime <= EndTime)
        {
            ddlTimeFrom.Items.Add(StartTime.ToShortTimeString());
            ddlTimeTo.Items.Add(StartTime.ToShortTimeString());
            StartTime = StartTime.Add(Interval);
        }
        ddlTimeFrom.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
        ddlTimeTo.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
    }
```

At first I wasn't using a gridview so I tend to call BindTime() inside page_load for the items in dropdownlist.. but now I need to edit it using gridview but I don't know how...Is it even possible? Cuz if it's not then I guess I'll just have to manually place each time on the Items..Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Handle the GridView RowEditing event and perform your custom logic there.
See this for details:
[Gridview row editing - dynamic binding to a DropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833490/gridview-row-editing-dynamic-binding-to-a-dropdownlist)