# How to show DropdownList in EditMode of GridView in ASP.Net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview1 and it has a normal field. 
After clicking edit link, I want to show a `DropdownList` that reads from my Database.
How can I achieve this?

this is my code for list template:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Course Name">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CName") %>'></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>

       <EditItemTemplate>

         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlECName"  CssClass="auto-style16" Width="80px" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>

           </EditItemTemplate>

           <FooterTemplate>

                  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCName"  CssClass="auto-style16" Width="80px" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>

            </FooterTemplate>

 </asp:TemplateField>
```

for adding values in ddl :

```
    //This code for adding values in course name list in the edit mood

 DropDownList ddlECName = ????? as DropDownList; 

                ddlECName.DataSource = GetData("SELECT * FROM TBCourse  INNER JOIN TbCourseMajor ON  TBCourse.CId = TbCourseMajor.CId  AND TbCourseMajor.MNom='" + DLMNom.SelectedValue + "'");


                ddlECName.DataTextField = "CName";
                ddlECName.DataValueField = "CId";
                ddlECName.DataBind();

                //Add Default Item in the DropDownList
                ddlECName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("----"));
```

The question is what should I write to define ddlECName ? how to tell them that I mean the ddl that in edit mode of grid view?

The second question is where to write this in which function ? Ex: OnRowEditing...etc

I have confusion in dealing with grid view methods if you know a good explanation please give the url.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would go in your RowDataBound event. So you will have to check the row state (edit) and bind the dropdown.

Please refer-
[Gridview row editing - dynamic binding to a DropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833490/gridview-row-editing-dynamic-binding-to-a-dropdownlist)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview_events(v=vs.110).aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36528/GridView-all-in-one